# How to disable fxcop

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a project created in visual studios 2010 pro, now opening it ultimate I am getting 100s of errors i belive because of fx cop.

How do I just simply turn it off.

I have right clicked and gone to code analysis, what setting do I have my website on?

EDIT:

the reason i need to turn it off because i get this main error:

```
Error   1   CA0060 : The indirectly-referenced assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' could not be found. This assembly is not required for analysis, however, analysis results could be incomplete. This assembly was referenced by: C:\CMS\packages\DataTablePager\DataTablePager.dll.     Application
```

[image]

Comment: Unless configured otherwise, FxCop is an external tool. You probably messed up something else. Your question is extremely vague.

Comment: i believe it comes with ultimate, i will add to my question reason why

Comment: @Cicada Code Analysis, a feature in VS 2010 Ultimate uses FXCop, so it does come with VS.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman It never said the contrary. I said it's external unless you configure it otherwise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right click on your project node in Solution Explorer, choose Properties.

There is a Code Analysis tab near the bottom.  Click that and uncheck "Enable Code Analysis on Build".

Alternatively, you could right click on that error, and choose "Suppress".  This will allow you to suppress that error from being generated.

Comment: i dont seem to have that option and this is the one error it does not let me supress

Comment: You clicked the wrong node.  Don't click the Solution Node (the top most node, click the project node (the second level in the tree).

Comment: Ah thank you.  I chose Uninstall.  Too many warnings and not easy to configure.

Answer (score 2):

Add `<RunCodeAnalysis>false</RunCodeAnalysis>` to your .csproj files (I slapped it in the first `<PropertyGroup>` I could find) and stop using `Analyze > Run Code Analysis` because that still runs the old FxCop.

If you use the old ASP.NET (not Core), right click on a project and click `Unload project` before you can edit the .csproj.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/fxcop-analyzers-faq?view=vs-2019

Comment: And this can be applied to a whole sln using a Directory.Build.props file with content
<Project>
 <PropertyGroup>
   <RunCodeAnalysis>false</RunCodeAnalysis>
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>